# How can I host a single MySQL database on multiple servers?

Tags: php, mysql, cluster-computing

I am newbie to programming. But I am going to work on a website that will have millions of records and huge traffic and I want to load balance my database of application server.

How can I create an application in PHP? and how can I distribute a single database on to multiple servers?

Comment: This question is too broad to be here.

Comment: please suggest where can I put this question.

Comment: IDK. You could probably try to rephrase your question to limit its scope, IMO. In it's current form this questions involves multiple questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out Hadoop. That is a very fine example of a distributed database system.
http://hadoop.apache.org/

Comment: Hadoop is not at all a DB. It's a **FS(distributed)+a computation framework(distributed)**. It is not meant for real-time,transactional or OLTP kinda stuff, for which DBs are generally used. Though there is another member of the Hadoop ecosystem, called **HBase**, which can be used for your DB needs. But it is **not** an SQL DB.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually meant HBase. And I didn't know SQL was a necessity.

Try this maybe? <http://www.severalnines.com/resources/clustercontrol-mysql-haproxy-load-balancing-tutorial>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get a detailed explanation here, as that kind of thing is quite complex. You may want to check out [MySQL Cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/).